# How to store multiples in a single variable comma seperated in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

How to store multiple values in single variable comma seperated.

I am getting the value of a feild named "ComponentID" and storing in variable"List".

I am doing a loop and getting the value of Component ID 10 items.

But each time it stores only the current value to the variable list.

I want all the 10 items to be stored in that variable named "List"

The output should be as (Item1,Item2,Item3.....Item 10)

I am looking for the syntax to obtain this in the selenium IDE... any suggestions

I am using the following code..

But dis store the Component ID for Cur Name in test.

I want all the 10 Component ID's to be stored in test comma seperated.

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>items</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>length</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>storedVars.items&lt;storedVars.length</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>Name[storedVars.items]</td>
    <td>CurName</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeValue</td>
    <td>id=ComponentID</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=customValue</td>
    <td>N</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars.items++;}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>endWhile</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Added the code..Any suggestions...In Vb i would use the following stOutput = stOutput & "," & c.Value.... I am nt sure how to use in the IDE..

Answer (score 1):

not exactly what you are asking but i have a related answer in my mind,

```
command:store

target:javascript{['value1','value2','value3']}

value:myVariable
```

this will randomly select any of the value and store it in myvariable

or if you wanted to use array for it, I have a perfect code

```
command:storeEval
target:new Array("item0","item1", "item2", "item3");
value:list
```

you cam access these using
    command:getEval
    target:list